# How do I assign chunks of code to objects in ggvis?

Tags: r, dplyr, ggvis

I am working at a shiny app and I thought it could be a nice idea to tidy up my code by creating a sort of stylesheet on a separate R file for my ggvis themes. Then I would like to invoke the "styling-chunks" whenever I need them in my main server.R script

So this is a sample bar-chart:

```
cars %>%
  distinct(speed) %>% 
  filter(speed<10) %>% 
  ggvis(x=~speed, y=~dist) %>%
  layer_bars(fill:="#73879C", stroke:="#73879C")
```

To which I would like to chain the following code

```
add_axis("y", title = "", grid=FALSE,
           properties= axis_props(
             labels = list(
               fill="#777"
             ),
             axis = list(stroke = "#fff")
           ))
```

I thought I could assign the `add_axis` to an object and then chain the object but it does not work. Here is what I mean:

```
eliminateGrid <- function(x){add_axis("y", title = "", grid=FALSE,
           properties= axis_props(
             labels = list(
               fill="#777"
             ),
             axis = list(stroke = "#fff")
           ))}


cars %>%
      distinct(speed) %>% 
      filter(speed<10) %>% 
      ggvis(x=~speed, y=~dist) %>%
      layer_bars(fill:="#73879C", stroke:="#73879C") %>%
  eliminateGrid()
```

I welcome any feedbacks not only on the reason why my code is not working, but also on whether my approach makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create a function that would pass `vis` object to `add_axis()`:

```
eliminateGrid <- function(vis){
  add_axis(vis = vis, type = "y", title = "", grid = FALSE,
           properties= axis_props(
             labels = list(
               fill="#777"),
             axis = list(stroke = "#fff")
           ))
  }
```